# Different Ember Routes or Displaying Two Complex Views in their own context

Tags: ember.js

I have an app with different related concerns. I have a list of items on the left that affect some of the items on the right (think Github Issues), but here's a mockup

[image]

All  fine, I click Item One and something happens on the right. However, the list on the left has its own routing requirements, it's a resource of items with nested routes. For example when we click on Create New Item we display a new form inline (see bottom left corner)

[image]

When I do that it, even if it's on a different outlet, it overrides what is currently rendered in other outlets. In this case the products on the right.

It would be ideal if we could just have different `routers` for different sections. I know I could just call render and create a new view/controller, but that would require me to handle my own states (am I creating a new item, editing  it, looking at the index, etc).

I'm currently looking into query-params as an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to register a different router and inject this into controllers. From ember's source code:

```
/**
@private

This creates a container with the default Ember naming conventions.
It also configures the container:
....
* all controllers receive the router as their `target` and `controllers`
  properties
*/

buildContainer: function(namespace) {
    var container = new Ember.Container();

    // some code removed for brevity... 
    container.register('controller:basic', Ember.Controller, { instantiate: false });
    container.register('controller:object', Ember.ObjectController, { instantiate: false });
    container.register('controller:array', Ember.ArrayController, { instantiate: false });
    container.register('route:basic', Ember.Route, { instantiate: false });

    container.register('router:main',  Ember.Router);

    container.injection('controller', 'target', 'router:main');
    container.injection('controller', 'namespace', 'application:main');

    container.injection('route', 'router', 'router:main');

    return container;
}
```

A second router could be created, registered with the container and injected into certain controllers:

```
    App.Router = Ember.Router.extend();
    App.Router.map function () {...}
```

Then to register

```
    container.register('router:secondary',  App.Router);
    container.injection('controller:list', 'target', 'router.secondary');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to solve this and ended up having a route that encompasses all the various routes that need to coexist render the rest of the parent routes with `{{render}}`, and making those routes' `renderTemplate` hook a NOOP (you have to do this specifically, or you will get assertion errors that you are using the singleton form of render twice).

However you don't have to manage your own state -- you can still use nested routes, and their model hooks, and since you are using the singleton form of `{{render}}` things will still automagically render into their correct spots. To say that another way: if you are using the singleton form of `{{render}}`, routes can set that controllers model, via the `model` hook if the route has the same name as the controller, or in either the `model` or `setupController` hook of another route using `controllerFor`.

You can also render into named outlets in the `renderTemplate` hooks, but I eventually abandoned that approach because I still had problems with disconnectOutlet getting called on things I didn't want disconnected.

Discussion on some outstanding issues indicate that there may eventually be a way to control whether/when routes get torn down and their outlets disconnected, but only when a way to do it has been worked out that won't increase the chance of memory leaks for people doing things the ordinary way.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood. I have product (right), lists (left), both routes with `renderTemplate: noop`. On application.hbs I render both explicitly. But there're a few problems. lists/index is never rendered, since it only renders lists when the active route is products. Minor thing. Most importantly, when I render of the nested routes (lists/new as in the second image above), it's rendered on the application's outlet instead of the lists outlet. That makes sense since the router doesn't know `lists` is active, since it was only rendered using `{{render}}`. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have a jsbin? and yes, once you go the `{{render}}` route it's `{{render}}` all the way down. I definitely don't think this way of doing things is ideal, but it did allow me to build an app with multiple routable simultaneously displayed master-detail lists.

Comment: I don't do you? I'll put one together to illustrate this in code.

Comment: Here's a version highlighting the issue: http://jsbin.com/Akihuyuy/4/edit and here's one that uses the noop http://jsbin.com/ekOmOR/1/edit. In the first one when I go to lists/new the products are removed. In the latter, nothing happens since there's no outlet to display it.

Comment: I found a solution that works in one direction. I'm currently rendering products from lists. Currently I don't have any routes there, so it will work until I need some more complex behavior there (soon). See http://jsbin.com/EDEnEZu/1/edit

Comment: I used my own state management logic in the parent controller and a bunch of horrible if statements to render the child controller/views. Not pretty, but reliable and easy to follow.

Comment: I have a deadline but will try to post an example eventually. And hopefully a blog post. I'm hoping if I widely publicize my admittedly crappy solution, a better way will be forthcoming from the Ember team.

Comment: Looking forward to it. Please remember to post a link when done. No rush, since I have a working solution, but I would certainly be happy to change it for something more generic and bounce ideas over an implementation. Thanks!