# How to preserve page rendering even if we go to different route and render view in different outlet?

Tags: ember.js

In our Ember.js app we have next scenario:

route1 - page1

route2 - page2

route3 - popUp dialog.

PopUp dialog can be showed from page1 or page2. This is not a problem to go to route3(PopUp dialog) from any page. But the main issue arises when we have to preserve background(page1 or page2) in case of PopUp dlg.

So, the question is: How to preserve page rendering even if we go to different route and render new view in different outlet?

Answer (score 0):

Four different answers.

1. Possibly the simplest for your situation is to duplicate the route. You might have page1/popUp and page2/popUp, both pointing to the same Router. If this is a common thing, you can write a macro to do this so you can apply this everywhere. It's not the most elegant, but it works. The URL can be bookmarked and still point to the same page and popUp.
2. Don't use routes for modals, simply open it and close it when done without navigating away.
3. Use a different router. (See [Different ember routes or displaying two complex views in their own context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111301/different-ember-routes-or-displaying-two-complex-views-in-their-own-context) for more info)
4. Use queryParams to do either 2 or 3, but still have the benefit of updating the URL.